# How to specify a controller and action in form to create new resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have QuestionsController and TrueFalseQuestionsController. I built a form to create question true/false, this is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @question, defaults: { error: false } do |question_form| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question</legend>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: question_form.object %>
    <%= question_form.input :content, input_html: { rows: 3, class: 'span6' } %>
    <%= question_form.input :mark, input_html: { class: 'span1' } %>
    <%= question_form.association :topic %>

    <%= question_form.simple_fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>    
      <%= answer_form.input :correct,
            collection: [[true, 'True'], [false, 'False']],
            as: :radio_buttons,
            label: 'Answer',
            value_method: :first,
            label_method: :last,
            item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>

    <%= question_form.button :submit, class: 'new_resource' %>
<% end %>
```

Now when I submit the form, it uses create action in QuestionsController, so how can I specify form to use create action in TrueFalseQuestionsController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you again :), so as I told you at the last question, if you had three partials for those three type of questions ready, just do it different in each partials. And i assume you had nested routes set right in the routes.rb

For example, at true false question form you can do

```
form_for @question, :url=>true_false_questions_path do |f|
```

Others do the same.

Comment: :) Thanks for answer, currently i decided to separate for three controllers.